# Changing theme in Semantic-UI

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm trying to change the default theme in Semantic-UI. I've modified the value `@site` in `src/theme.config` to `'material'` (for instance) then ran `gulp build`. The directory dist is regenerated.

I then copied the content of dist directory into my website resources, but no theme applies when I watch the result in my browser. For instance, buttons look'n'feel is default (navigator default).

Semantic-UI documentation is far from complete, I can't make this work. I'm using latest version (npm install), is this a bug or am I missing something ?

Also, I can't see my theme in the `dist/themes` directory. Also, gulp generation is 5 seconds quicker when theme is not default, I believe this is not normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

After many trial and errors and googling, it worked for me.

Step 1:
Make sure that the default theme folder is there. I removed my default theme folder for some testing and it didn't work. After I bring it back and executed `gulp build`, then it worked.

Step 2:
You may need to update your `node` to latest version. The theme generation started to work after I updated node version from `5.2.0` to `5.6.0`.

Also:
You may run `gulp watch` and do some changes in `theme.config`. It will show you the theme building process details.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, this is a very old post. I totally dropped Semantic-UI since I could not make it work using the documentation. I can't tell if your solution will work.